# CUBE error Process

Tags: ssas-2012

Im trying to Process SSAS cube, its deployed correctly. but I got list of errors through process the cube : 
Error Examples:

1. OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login timeout expired; HYT00; A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.; 08001; Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5]. ; 08001.
2. Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Sales DW', Name of 'Sales DW'.
3. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Date', Name of 'Dim Date' was being processed.
4. OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login timeout expired; HYT00; A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.; 08001; Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5]. ; 08001.
5. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Sales Person', Name of 'Dim Sales Person' was being processed.

Comment: Run it again and this time look for warnings in addition to errors. Usually it is a warning that's the root cause error (silly as that sounds)

Comment: I did, it working now. It seems the server connection issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems the server connection issue